# SQL Server Compact Code First: Database not created

Tags: entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, code-first

I want to use Entity Framework code first to create a SQL Server Compact DB. 
I first created the model classes, then the DB context:

```
public class Peng_Rob_BinaryInteractions
{
    [Key]
    public int PID { get; set; }
    public int ID1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Value { get; set; }
}
public class RefData
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Mwt { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Tc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Pc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Omega { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Hoffset { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> P1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> P2 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> P3 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> P4 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> P5 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> P6 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> P7 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> TC_K { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> PC_K { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Tr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Ha_a { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Ha_b { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Ha_c { get; set; }

    public Nullable<double> Entropy_Offset { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The `DbContext` class:

```
public class AddinDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Peng_Rob_BinaryInteractions> Peng_Rob_BinaryInteractions { set; get; }
    public DbSet<RefData> RefData { set; get; }

    static AddinDBContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<AddinDBContext>(new DbInitializer());
        //using (AddinDBContext db = new AddinDBContext())
        //    db.Database.Initialize(false);
    }

    public static AddinDBContext Create()
    {
        return new AddinDBContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class DbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<AddinDBContext>{
    //Seed method here
}
```

And inside the *app.config* file, I added the connection string:

```
<add name="AddinDBContext" 
        connectionString="Data Source=D:\GTDB.sdf"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
```

I debugged the code and there is no exception, but I can't find the database inside the d at all or any other place; the database is not created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add this to app.config in the startup project?

Comment: No the DB context and the classes are in a project that i reference from the startup project

Comment: You need to add the connection string to the startup project

Comment: Yes , it's working fine. I forgot to add the connection string to the startup project. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the connection string to the startup project.